# Python calculator that stores sums in txt file. which can then be called to print entire txt file when asked?

Tags: python

I am currently learning the basics of Python and have been asked to create a calculator on python that has four functions (+-*/) and will add all sums and answers into a txt.file as well as printing the sum and answer to the user. This txt file must print all sums/answers when asked.

The code i currently have will perform as a basic calculator and will create the txt. file and will add the sum/ans to it.

However i am struggling to write the code that will read the file and print it out in the terminal.

Please can I have some critique of my overall code and also ways to achieve my task of printing the sums added to the txt.file.

```
sum_file = open("equations.txt", "a")
def calculate() :
    math_op = input('''
    Please type in the operation you would like to perform: 
    + for addition
    - for subtraction
    * for multiplication
    / for division)
    ''')

  
    number1 = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
    number2 = float(input("Please enter your second number: "))

    if math_op == '+':
        print(f'{number1} + {number2} = ')
        print(number1 + number2)
        sum_file.write(f'{number1} + {number2} = ')
        sum_file.write(str(number1 + number2))
        sum_file.write("\n")

    elif math_op == '-':
        print(f'{number1} - {number2} = ')
        print(number1 - number2)
        sum_file.write(f'{number1} - {number2} = ')
        sum_file.write(str(number1 - number2 ))
        sum_file.write("\n")

    elif math_op == '*':
        print(f'{number1} * {number2} = ')
        print(number1 * number2)
        sum_file.write(f'{number1} * {number2} = ')
        sum_file.write(str(number1 * number2))
        sum_file.write("\n")

    elif math_op == '/':
        print(f'{number1} / {number2} = ')
        print(number1 / number2)
        sum_file.write(f'{number1} / {number2} = ')
        sum_file.write(str(number1 / number2))
        sum_file.write("\n")

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator, please run the program again.')


    calc_history = input('''
     would you like to see the calculators history? 
    if yes please type "Y" and if no please type "N" )
    ''')

    if calc_history == "Y":
        sum_file.read 
        print(sum_file)

    elif calc_history == "N":
        calculate()

    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option: ")
calculate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close it and reopen it in read mode to read the file. Try changing

```
if calc_history == "Y":
    sum_file.read 
    print(sum_file)
```

To

```
if calc_history == "Y":
    sum_file.close()
    sum_file = open("equations.txt", "r")
    print(sum_file.read())
    sum_file.close()
    sum_file = open("equations.txt", "a")
```

First I close the file, than I open it in read mode, print it, than I close it again, and reopen it in append mode. I would also suggest adding `calc_history.capitalize()`, right after you set it from input, that way the user can use capital, or non capital letters, and it will still work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! the capitalize function is a good tip too :)